# Simple JSF webapp running on tomcat 7 and not on JBoss EWS 2.0 on Openshift

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jboss, openshift, jsf-2.2

I keep failing to make a simple MyFaces 2.2 / DeltaSpike 1.1.0 / PrimeFaces 5.1 / Weld 2.2.0.Final work in the JBoss EWS 2.0 cartridge of Openshift.

As far as I understand, this cartridge is supposed to provide a Tomcat 7 container.

When I download tomcat 7.0.54 binary distrib, unpack it and just debug or run my app on my host, it just works.

When I try to start the same app on OpenShift' JBoss EWS 2.0 (which features a tomcat 7.0.54 as the logs state), it does not really run.

I have a simple xhtml test file, accueil.xhtml, which contains :

```
    <h:form>
        <p:panelGrid columns="1">
            <!-- ok -->
            <h:outputText value="Hello JSF World !"/>

            <!-- ok -->
            <h:outputText value="#{'test3'}"/>

            <!-- ok -->
            <h:outputText value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}"/>

            <!-- ok -->
            <h:outputText value="#{facesContext.externalContext.contextName}"/>

            <!-- ko -->
            <h:outputText value="#{testBean.test1}"/>

            <!-- ko -->
            <h:outputText value="#{testBean.uneMethode('Test2')}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

The two last outputs are just empty.

The bean is dead simple :

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    @Getter
    private String test1 = "Test1";

    public String uneMethode(String test) {
        return "Une Methode : " + test;
    }
}
```

(I first wanted to test @ViewAccessScoped, but sticked back to @SessionScoped, just to check the pb was not specific to this first scope handling).

My context.xml is quite simple too :

```
<Context docBase="ROOT" path="/ROOT" reloadable="true" allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" jndiExceptionOnFailedWrite="false" >
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
    <Resource name="BeanManager"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
              factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory">
    </Resource>
</Context>
```

I tried to define a docBase and a path, but it fails without it too.

My web.xml is quite standard too :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

     <display-name>Test application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>accueil.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.SUBMIT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- JSF standard parameters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>
            If this parameter is set to true and the submitted value of a component is
            the empty string, the submitted value will be set to null
        </description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: "client" or "server" (= default)
            See JSF Specification 2.5.3</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- MyFaces specific parameters -->
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if state saving method is "server" (= default).
            Defines the amount (default = 20) of the latest views are stored in session.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>20</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if state saving method is "server" (= default).
            If true (default) the state will be serialized to a byte stream before it
            is written to the session.
            If false the state will not be serialized to a byte stream.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if state saving method is "server" (= default) and if
            org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION is true (= default)
            If true (default) the serialized state will be compressed before it
            is written to the session. If false the state will not be compressed.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in the
            rendered HTML output.
            If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
            that submits the corresponding form.
            If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
            will be added as url parameters.
            Default: "true"</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is "human readable".
            i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
            influence the HTML code.
            Default: "true"</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
            former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
            with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
            if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
            Default: "false"</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- desactivation du support des JSP (voir https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3078 )-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SUPPORT_JSP</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- ne jamais relire les fichiers XHTML -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- aucun check de duplicité d'id en prod (voir http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html#org_apache_myfaces_CHECK_ID_PRODUCTION_MODE) -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_ID_PRODUCTION_MODE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- voir http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html#org_apache_myfaces_VIEW_UNIQUE_IDS_CACHE_ENABLED -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.VIEW_UNIQUE_IDS_CACHE_ENABLED</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- voir http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html#org_apache_myfaces_CACHE_EL_EXPRESSIONS -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CACHE_EL_EXPRESSIONS</param-name>
        <param-value>strict</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- voir http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html#org_apache_myfaces_SAVE_STATE_WITH_VISIT_TREE_ON_PSS -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SAVE_STATE_WITH_VISIT_TREE_ON_PSS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

</web-app>
```

My pom.xml is very simple too :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>testlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>testlp</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <name>testlp</name>
        <repositories>
                <repository>
                        <id>eap</id>
                        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
                        <releases>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                        <id>eap</id>
                        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
                        <releases>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
<!--
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
                </dependency>
-->
    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.6</version>
      <!-- on prend toujours ce package afin d'avoir acces a ViewNotFoundException 
      <scope>runtime</scope>-->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Specifications -->
    <!-- JSR-330 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-299 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-jcdi_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-interceptor_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-validation_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-el_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-jsp_2.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.buildtools</groupId>
      <artifactId>myfaces-builder-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- primefaces -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>5.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-jsf-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-jsf-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-security-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-security-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-bean-validation-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-bean-validation-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
       <artifactId>deltaspike-servlet-module-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.0</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
       <artifactId>deltaspike-servlet-module-impl</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.0</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
               <version>7.0.54</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
           </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.54</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
        <profiles>
                <profile>
                        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                                invoking mvn. -->
                        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                                will need. -->
                        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
                                folder. -->
                        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
                        <id>openshift</id>
                        <build>
                                <finalName>testlp</finalName>
                                <plugins>
                                        <plugin>
                                                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                                <version>2.1.1</version>
                                                <configuration>
                                                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                                                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                                                </configuration>
                                        </plugin>
                                </plugins>
                        </build>
                </profile>
        </profiles>
</project>
```

beans.xml is almost empty :

```
<beans  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd" />
```

And faces-config.xml too :

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
              version="2.2">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>fr_FR</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

I found however the following difference in servers logs. Locally, I have :

```
INFO: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
nov. 25, 2014 3:23:20 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 2.2.0 (Final)
nov. 25, 2014 3:23:20 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
```

On the OpenShift gear, I have :

```
INFO: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
Nov 25, 2014 9:21:33 AM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 2.2.0 (Final)
Nov 25, 2014 9:21:34 AM org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.deployment.URLScanner handleURL
WARN: Not implemented.
Nov 25, 2014 9:21:35 AM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
```

Is there a problem with the way JBoss deploys the WAR ? I read miscelanous problems with VFS...

Any help welcomed !